# Get results from group calculation in iReport 4.5.1

Tags: charts, jasper-reports, ireport

I have created a report in *iReport 4.5.1* that displays the results of a jdbc query in the detail band, with a group that contains some calculation variables. I need to display the group calculation results in a chart in ascending order by value and/or list the results in the summary to graph them from there. Their position on the x-axis is not important, as long as the y values ascend from left to right.

So far, I have tried the following:

1. Created a chart straight from the group values, but I cannot sort the values the way I want them. They are always displayed in the order they are presented in the report.
2. Used the report with the group calculations as a subreport and tried to return the values in as a list in the master report detail band and graph them from there. I was only able to produce either a single value once (the first or last value in the group), or a single value repeated multiple times (based on row count from master report query).
3. Nest the detail band and group band inside another group to list the results in the outer group. Again, I am only able to return a single result.

My experience with *iReport* is minimal, so I am hoping that I am missing something simple. Can anyone offer a solution or advice?

**Edit:
I need to display the group calculation results in a chart in ascending order by value and/or list the results in the summary to graph them from there. I would love to post my screenshots, but I don't have the rep.**

P.S. - The jrxml is over 1k lines. Is there a specific section that I should post, or just post the whole thing?

Comment: You should post the jrxml file and the screenshot of exporting result. What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do this is by putting a sub-report on your report.  If you are using any parameters in your report you can pass them to your sub-report.  In the sub-report query you can group at the grouping level that you need and order the results any way you like.  You can also perform any calculations that you need and create your chart.  Then put this subreport in your summary section or a group footer and you should be good to go.